# I am getting error A1000: cannot open file: Irvine32.inc however I included in the code and posted the right directory in the linker

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32, masm32

I am writing a program in MASM that will clear the screen, prompt the user for two integers, and perform the arithmetic and then output it back. However, I can not call Clrscr because the compiler apparently can't open the file Irvine32.inc. Is there a formatting issue I am having but not seeing? I have consulted Irvine's "Assembly Language for 86x Processors," eight edition, but can not find the answer there either.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:dword

IntegerCount = 3        ; Size of the array. 

.data
    str1 BYTE "Enter an integer: ", 0
    str2 BYTE "The sum of these intergers is: ", 0
    array DWORD IntegerCount DUP(?)

.code
main PROC
        call WaitMsg
        call Clrscr
        mov esi, OFFSET array
        mov ecx, IntegerCount

        invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

I have looked it up, and all I could really find was to add `INCLUDE Irvine32.inc` or `INCLUDELIB Irvine32.lib` but am having trouble there as well.

I have also tried to add the folder the code is in the same directory that the Irvine32.inc file is in, but that will not work either.

Like I said, perhaps I am making a formatting mistake, but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have specified the specific file path after INCLUDE and the build now succeeds.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).